# Trying to store a string representation of an email from php to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, email, mysqli

I'm trying to get an email from a user on an HTML5 page via a text field and pass it via POST to a PHP processing page which then updates a MySQL table with the email.

The line for email input on HTML5 page:

```
<input id="emailBox" size="30" type="email" placeholder="Email address" style="display: none"  />
```

The relevant PHP code:

```
<?php

        $mysql = new mysqli("localhost","USERNAME","PASSWORD", "DATABASE_NAME");
        if ($mysql->connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }

        $email = $mysql -> real_escape_string($_POST[2]);

        if($email != "null"){ //the HTML5 page passes NULL as String "null"
            echo "<h3>" . $email . " will receive an email notification in " . ($duration-5) . " minutes.</h3>";
        }
        echo "<br>This page will redirect in 5  seconds.";

        try{
            $mysql->query("START TRANSACTION");
            $query = "UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET email='" . $email . "' WHERE id=" . $A_VARIABLE;

            if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }
            $mysql->commit();
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo "An error occured.";
            $mysql->rollback();
        }
        $mysql->close();
?>
```

A friend told me that there was a special way to escape string variables, but I haven't found how to do that yet. I also tried it without the ' " ' surrounding $email , but it didn't make any difference.  There is no crash, and the value in the database changes from NULL to "", but an empty String is as useless for sending emails as NULL. If anyone can give an example of the correct syntax that would be awesome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't found out how to do that? Have you looked?

Comment: I've searched using Google multiple times and for some reason I can't seem to find anything that gets it to work... I would expect it to be something extremely simple, so I'm left scratching my head... any suggestions?

Comment: Hang on - so what's 'real_escape_string'?

Comment: It's supposed to format a String so that it can be read into and out of a database. Also prevents people from using a text input to access the database. Or so the description said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must be missing something. What's wrong with this...

```
$query = "
UPDATE TABLE_NAME 
   SET email = '$email' 
 WHERE id = $A_VARIABLE;
```

Comment: In all honesty that is what has me stumped. I don't understand why it doesn't work. It is really frustrating me. I have other updates in the code that work just fine, the only difference is that they are numeric values. int values to be specific.

Comment: Thank you for your help, just found that I had previously commented out the line that actually performed the query when I launched the site in order to prevent any issues.